# Equality of Minimal & characteristic polynomial implying diagonizability

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I know a matrix is diagonizable iff minimal polynomial splits into linear factors. Obviously as the Jordan block would have only 1*1 blocks, containing eigenvalues. 
Is there any further simplification on the case where minimal and characteristic polynomials are same.

Say, characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial of $A$ are $x^4$ , then the Jordan block would contain 0 in diagoanal entries and 1 in super diagoanal entries.and then it should not be diagonizable. Correct? Am I missing any point?

Comment: Well, at least if your eigenvalues have small multiplicity, this won't help. Consider your matrix to have only eigenvalues of multiplicity =1, then characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial are the same, but the matric can be diagonalized.

Comment: I know a matrix is diagonizable iff minimal polynomial splits into *distinct* linear factors.

Comment: @Babelfish so if  the Jordan block would contain 1 in diagoanal entries and 1 in super diagoanal entries, the characteristic polynomial is (x-1)^4 and so is it's minimal polynomial. Then would it diagonizable?

Comment: And it is splitting. Oh it should be diagonizable

Comment: If minimal polynomial = cp = $(X-1)^4$, then the matrix is definitely NOT diagonizable (as the jordan normal form is unique and has a block of length 4). But if, for example, minimal polynomial = characteristic polynomial = $X(X-1)(X-2)$, the matrix IS diagonizable.